# Stripe Integration in Live-wire

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-livewire, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to implement stripe in Laravel Livewire. I've generated the stripe token in blade.php file using Javascript. Now I want to use the token in backend to make a transition.
But the payment Method in component is not working.

Here is the Relevant Code:

livewire Component Method:

```
public function stripePost(Request $request)
{
    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    Stripe\Charge::create ([
        "amount" => 100 * 100,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "source" => $request->stripeToken,
        "description" => "This payment is tested purpose phpcodingstuff.com"
    ]);
   
    Session::flash('success', 'Payment successful!');
    return back();
}
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: Are you handling the [Stripe webhooks](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#handling-stripe-webhooks) ? If not, you need to setup a way to handle Stripe webhooks. [This](https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/best-practices-for-stripe-elements-w-livewire-alpine/1029/6) is a good example how you could handle payments in livewire with the help of a poll component answered by Snapey